# Display contents of a Content Note on a Classic Task Email Template using Task WhoId (relatedTo)

Tags: process-builder, email-template, python, simple-salesforce, amazon-aws

I am trying to display the values of the Content Note object's content field that is related to a lead record and I want to display those values on a task email. Thanks.
We use AWS Python Lambda integration (and the simple salesforce library) to handle some of the updating of leads, contacts, and creation of new tasks while Salesforce sends out the email notifications to the sales staff using  Process Builder processes.

> Q) Can I add the Content Notes values on an email template using both the relatedTo and WhoId email merge fields within the Classic email template on Task object?

Here is the python integration code used to call the function that creates and links the Content Note to the lead/contact:

```
 print('ARE WE CUSTOMER LINK: '+ str(file_type) +' HERES THE FLAG: '+ str(result_flag))
        if (file_type == 'CustomerLink' or file_type == 'RightSource' or  file_type == 'Weber') and result_flag:
            print(' << Tasks Needed: CustomerLink or Weber or Right  Source >>')
            #starting to create task
            task_info = prepare_task_data(recordInfo,temp_user_id,ReceivedAt)
            if bool(task_info):
                print('creates a task')
                #creates a task
                try:
                    file_type_response = sf.Task.create(json.loads(task_info))
                    if file_type_response.get('success') == True:
                        logger.processed_records_logging('Create', 'Task', file_type_response.get('id'))
                        print('<< RelatedID >> ',file_type_response.get('id'))
                        Success = 201
                        #NOW, CREATE NOTES
                        if 'Notes' in recordInfo:
                            notes = recordInfo['Notes']
                            print('<< NOTES >>',notes)
                            Id = recordInfo['Id']
                            if Id.startswith('003'):
                                Type = 'Contact'
                            elif Id.startswith('00Q'):
                                Type = 'Lead'
                            if 'MQP_Type__c'  in recordInfo and recordInfo['MQP_Type__c'] == "Web Visitor Intel":
                                content_notes = notes
                                print('<< CONTENT NOTES >> ',content_notes)
                                #content_note_info = format_content_note_data(recordInfo,content_notes)
                                #notes = content_notes_info
                            created_notes = salesforce.prepare_create_notes(Id, Type, notes, recordInfo)
                            print('<< CREATED NOTES >> ',created_notes)
                           
                                #content_note_info = salesforce.prepare_content_note_data(recordInfo,file_type_response.get('OwnerId'),file_type_response.get('id'))
                    else:
                        logger.unprocessed_records_logging('Create','Task','Unable to Create Task')
                        Success = 403
                except Exception as e:
                    logger.unprocessed_records_logging('Create','Task',e)
```

> Here is the python integration code used to create the Content Note:

```
# Creates and assingn notes to Lead or Contact
def prepare_create_notes(self, Id,type_of,content, temp_dic):
    print('prepare_create_notes')
    try:
        self.subject = 'Note for'
        if 'MQP_Type__c' in temp_dic and temp_dic['MQP_Type__c'] !='' and 'ghg' in str(temp_dic['MQP_Type__c']).lower():
            self.subject ='GHG Inquiry note from '
        if 'FirstName' in temp_dic and temp_dic['FirstName'] != '':
            self.subject = self.subject + ' ' + temp_dic['FirstName']
        if 'LastName' in temp_dic and temp_dic['LastName'] != '':
            self.subject = self.subject + ' ' + temp_dic['LastName']
        if 'Company' in temp_dic and temp_dic['Company'] != '':
            self.subject = self.subject + ' from ' + temp_dic['Company']
        self.content = re.sub('&','&amp;', content.rstrip())
        self.content = re.sub("'","&#39;", self.content.rstrip())
        self.content = re.sub('"','&quot;', self.content.rstrip())
        self.content = re.sub('<','&lt;', self.content.rstrip())
        self.content = re.sub('>','&gt;', self.content.rstrip())
        self.content = base64.b64encode(bytes(self.content, 'utf-8'))
        self.content = self.content.decode("utf-8")
        self.notes_dict = { 'Title': self.subject, 'Content': self.content}
        # Insertion of Notes
        self.insert_notes = self.__sf.ContentNote.create(self.notes_dict)
        if self.insert_notes['success'] == True:
            self.__logging.processed_records_logging('Create','Note',self.insert_notes['id'])
            #Creating Notes Link to Lead/Contact
            self.linking_dict = {"ContentDocumentId" : self.insert_notes['id'], "LinkedEntityId" : Id, "ShareType" : "V"}
            self.linking_notes_contact = self.__sf.ContentDocumentLink.create(self.linking_dict)
            if self.linking_notes_contact['success'] == True:
                self.__logging.processed_records_logging('Create','LinkingNote', self.linking_notes_contact['id'])
                return {'ContentNoteId': self.insert_notes['id'],'ContentDocumentLink': self.linking_notes_contact['id']}
            else:
                self.__logging.unprocessed_records_logging('Create','LinkingNote','Unable to Link Note to Contact/Lead')
                return {}
        else:
            self.__logging.unprocessed_records_logging('Create','Note','Unable to Create Note')
            return {}
    except Exception as e:
        print('in prepare notes handler')
        print(e)
        self.__logging.unprocessed_records_logging('Create','Note',e)
        return {}
```

> Here is the csv file containing the contents in red that will be loaded into the content field of the Content Note object record:
> [image]

> Finally, here is the  Email Template we need to use (Note The contents from the Content Note would be displayed within the red rectangle):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok I just found out that I should use the 4th email template option which is: VisualForce email template. It will allow for the population large amounts of dynamic data using the "relation To" field (Lead/Contact) from the  "recipient" field (Task).:

1. Create a Long Area Text custom field on Contact.
2. Create a Long Area Text custom field on Lead

Both of these will store the dynamic data of up to 131K characters.
Then create  a Visual Force email Template as in an example below:

> https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_email_templates_creating.htm